# NullPointerException - FXMLLoader.constructLoadException

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I seem not to find a fitting solution to my problem. 
I always get a NPE while loading the EntryView.fxml file.
I`ve already tried several path formats (e.g. relative, absolute).
Am I having a missconcept of how it works or is it a simple mistake?
All these files are in one package.

Here is the top part of the error log:

```
    Mär 13, 2015 1:09:26 PM de.quest2go.authortool.entry.EntryController$1 handle
SCHWERWIEGEND: null
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
/Users/timzeidler/Uni/MCS/AuthortoolI/bin/de/quest2go/authortool/entry/EventEditView.fxml:9

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:918)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2701)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2521)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
        at de.quest2go.authortool.entry.EntryController$1.handle(EntryController.java:64)
        at de.quest2go.authortool.entry.EntryController$1.handle(EntryController.java:1)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8216)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /EventEditController.java
```

The short FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="EntryContoller.java">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="eventBtn" layoutX="91.0" layoutY="319.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="EventScene" />
      <Button layoutX="270.0" layoutY="319.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="ItemScene" />
      <Button layoutX="457.0" layoutY="319.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="EpisodeScene" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

And the Main:

```
public class EntryMain extends Application {
        private Stage stage;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(EntryMain.class, (java.lang.String[])null);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            stage = primaryStage;
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EntryView.fxml"));
                //VBox page = (VBox) FXMLLoader.load(EntryMain.class.getResource("EntryView.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle("Autorentool");
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EntryMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

And the controller with the FXMlLoader with the problem.

```
public class EntryController {

        private Node node;
        private Stage stage;
        private Scene scene;
        private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
        private Parent root;

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;

    @FXML // fx:id="episodenEditorBtn"
    private Button episodenEditorBtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="eventEditorBtn"
    private Button eventEditorBtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="itemEditorBtn"
    private Button itemEditorBtn; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    void initialize() {
        assert episodenEditorBtn != null : "fx:id=\"episodenEditorBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EntryView.fxml'.";
        assert eventEditorBtn != null : "fx:id=\"eventEditorBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EntryView.fxml'.";
        assert itemEditorBtn != null : "fx:id=\"itemEditorBtn\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'EntryView.fxml'.";

        eventEditorBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                                try {
                            stage = new Stage();
                            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EventEditView.fxml"));
                                //VBox page = (VBox) FXMLLoader.load(EntryMain.class.getResource("EntryView.fxml"));
                            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                            stage.setScene(scene);
                            stage.setTitle("Autorentool");
                            stage.show();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(EntryMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                        }


        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Your controller needs to be in a package and the `<fx:controller>` attribute must reference it with the fully-qualified class name (i.e. `package-name.Class-name`)

Comment: (By the way, nowhere in the stack trace does it say there is a `NullPointerException`.)

Comment: ok thanks, I´ll try it as soon as i get home. I thought so because at the top it says null